# Recoger los valores de un formulario y mostrarlos

Tags: php, html, netbeans

Estoy empezando a programar con php. Para empezar estoy haciendo cosas sencillas. Esta vez me gustaría que mi aplicación tomase los datos escrito en el formulario y que se muestre una cadena de texto con los datos recibidos al pulsar un botón. Me gustaría saber cómo puedo recoger esos datos con php y luego mostrarlos en una cadena. Este es el código que tengo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Hola</title>
    
<h1>Formulario</h1>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="index.php">
        <?php
            $name = '<p>Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre" size="40"></p>';
            $fecha = '<p>Fecha de nacimiento: 
                    <input type="date" id="start" name="trip-start"
                    value="2018-07-22"
                    min="1950-01-01" max="2029-12-31">
                    </p>';
            
            $sexo = '<p>Sexo:
                <input type="radio" name="hm" value="h"> Hombre
                <input type="radio" name="hm" value="m"> Mujer
                </p>';
            
            
        ?>
        <p>
          <input type="submit" value="Enviar" onClick="funcion($name)">              
        </p>
    </form>
    
    <?php
        // put your code here
        $a = $GLOBALS["name"];
               
        function funcion($a){
            '<p>Hola'.$a.'</p>';
        }
    ?>     
</body>
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** En la cabecera de tu formulario declara el método por el cual se enviarán los datos:

Antes:

```
<form action="index.php">
```

Ahora:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
```

**2.** No necesitas el evento `onClick()` y usar un input de tipo submit
( `type="submit"` ) a la vez.

Modifica la linea:

```
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" onClick="funcion($name)">
```

Así:

```
<input type="submit" value="Enviar">
```

3. Por último obtén los datos, por el método POST. (coloca arriba justo después de `<body>`):

   ```
    <?php
       $nombre = isset($_POST["nombre"]) ? $_POST["nombre"] : 'nulo';
       $sexo = isset($_POST["hm"]) ? $_POST["hm"] : 'nulo';

       echo '<p>El nombre es: '.$nombre.' y el sexo es: '.$sexo.'</p>';
    ?>
   ```

Comment: Genial, sí funciona. Pero lo que no logro entender (ya ajeno al problema que tengo) es cómo asignarle una acción a cada botón en caso de que tuviese más botones. Porque en este caso no veo que tenga algún vínculo el botón con la acción a realizar. Gracias,

Comment: Para lo que estás pidiendo, en lugar de `<input type="submit"...` sería `<input type="button"...`. y así utilizar el evento `onClick()` de ***JavaScript***.  De todos modos, si tu problema está resuelto, ***considera cerrar este hilo y haz una nueva pregunta, para recibir nuevas respuestas.***

Answer (score 1):

Varias cosas:

Estás guardando variables (`$name`, `$fecha` y `$sexo`) que contienen cadenas de texto con los campos del formulario, en lugar de mostrarlos en él. Tienes que incluir ese código HTML directamente en el formulario, que no requiere de código PHP o Javascript, sólo necesitas HTML.

Además, estás mezclando Javascript y PHP. Cuando llamas a la función `funcion()` en el `onclick` de tu botón, estás usando Javascript, pero la función como tal la estás declarando en PHP. Realmente tampoco te hace falta una función para obtener el valor del campo que estás recogiendo.

También, **y esto es lo más importante para empezar**, te recomiendo que te familiarices con los métodos POST y GET, que son los que recogen los datos del formulario y te permiten trasladarlos a tu código PHP.

En este ejemplo, al formulario en HTML le añado un pequeño código PHP arriba donde obtiene el valor del campo *nombre* usando `filter_input()` (https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.filter-input.php), comprueba con la función `empty()` (https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php) si la variable no está vacía y, si la condición se cumple, imprime el saludo por pantalla:

```
<?php

$nombre = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nombre');

if ( ! empty($nombre)) {
    echo '<p>Hola ' . $nombre  . '</p>';
}

?>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <p>Nombre:</p>
    <p><input type="text" name="nombre" size="40"></p>
    <p>Fecha de nacimiento:</p>
    <p><input type="date" id="start" name="trip-start" value="2018-07-22" min="1950-01-01" max="2029-12-31"></p>
    <p>Sexo:</p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="hm" value="h"> Hombre</p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="hm" value="m"> Mujer</p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Enviar"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Hola. Si yo pongo el código así me marca una advertencia: "Do not access Superglobal $_POST Array Directly" y no carga correctamente.

Comment: El código debería de funcionar, pero es posible que en Netbeans dé problemas porque he puesto un ejemplo demasiado básico. Te edito la respuesta añadiendo `filter_input()`, que es la manera más segura de obtener un valor tanto con POST como con GET.

Comment: Genial, ahora sí que se me quita la advertencia. pero no me muestra nada  ¿Para que muestre el texto al pulsar el botón debo usar las funciones function()? Gracias.

Comment: No hace falta ninguna función, simplemente basta con que le escribas un nombre en el formulario, le des a enviar y te devolverá el mismo formulario con un saludo ("Hola ...") en la parte superior.